# how to extract columns from rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have data in txt file. Here is the link to the data: [Link](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/ibratusmonov/startup).The data is stored as a single column. But I need to extract columns from rows. When I read the data using `pd.read_table()` method, it returns as a single column and many rows. For example, I have `.txt` file like that:

```
Date: 23:15
Temperature: 20 C
Humidity: 40
CO2 level: 14
Date: 23:20
Temperature: 28 C
Humidity: 45
CO2 level: 18
Date: 23:25
Temperature: 35 C
Humidity: 35
CO2 level: 20
Date: 23:30
Temperature: 22 C
Humidity: 52
CO2 level: 12
```

and more .....

As you can see, the Date, Temperature, Humidity, CO2 are repeating, so they should be treated as columns, and values they assign should be treated as rows respect to its category. For example:

| Date | Temperature | Humidity | CO2 level |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 23:15 | 20 C | 40 | 14 |
| 23:20 | 28 C | 45 | 18 |
| 23:25 | 35 C | 35 | 20 |
| 23:30 | 22 C | 52 | 12 |

it should assign like that

Comment: So you'd have only one row as output?

Comment: No this is just for illustration. I have 11 columns and more than 1000 rows ( if it is in this format)

Comment: What if you cloud find all lines that `startswith()` each column name.

Comment: I don't need to find lines, I need to make a table using these data.

Comment: I updated the format, please check that it's faithful. You must put the content between triple backticks to ensure that it's formatted as code/raw text.

Comment: I edited and added the link to the original data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have several target rows, [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html), use one item as a reference to start groups (here `Date`) and [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) or [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
out = (pd.read_csv(filename, header=None)[0]
         .str.split(r':\s*', n=1, expand=True)
         .assign(index=lambda d: d[0].eq('Date').cumsum())
         .set_index(['index', 0])[1].unstack(sort=False)
         .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
       )
```

Or, with a `pivot`, which won't maintain the column order:

```
out = (pd.read_csv(filename, header=None)[0]
         .str.split(r':\s*', n=1, expand=True)
         .assign(index=lambda d: d[0].eq('Date').cumsum())
         .pivot(index='index', columns=0, values=1)
       )
```

Output:

```
    Date Temperature Humidity CO2 level
1  23:15        20 C       40        14
2  23:20        28 C       45        18
3  23:25        35 C       35        20
4  23:30        22 C       52        12
```

Adapted to the kaggle dataset, using the temperature (Температура) as reference:

```
out = (pd.read_csv(filename, sep='# no sep #', engine='python', header=None)[0]
         .str.split(r':\s*', n=1, expand=True)
         .assign(index=lambda d: d[0].eq('Температура').cumsum())
         .set_index(['index', 0])[1].unstack(sort=False)
         .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
      )
```

---

###### original answer

Assuming you want one row and many columns as output, you could [`split`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and [`transpose`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html):

```
out = (pd.read_csv(filename, header=None)[0]
         .str.split(r':\s*', n=1, expand=True)
         .set_index(0).rename_axis(None).T
       )
```

*NB. there should be no comma in the data. Else, pick a non-existent separator.*

Alternatively, if you only have one `:` per row:

```
out = (pd.read_csv(filename, sep=': *', header=None, engine='python')
         .set_index(0).rename_axis(None).T
       )
```

Output:

```
  Temperature Humidity 1 Humidity2 Level of CO2   date
1        20 C         45        50           12  12:25
```

Comment: No, I need "Humidity", " Temperature" etc as columns and values of them should be rows. In dataset the humidity, Temperature, etc are repetitive, so they should be treated as columns, and the values they have should be treated as rows.

Comment: Then be explicit, update your question to provide a complete input example and the extract matching expected output

Comment: I think now it is understandable)

Comment: @IbratUsmonov it's better thanks, see update

Comment: I added link to the original data, you can look. By the way either way you provided does not work(((. I hope you will help me.

Comment: @IbratUsmonov my approach works, but you need to adapt it. Obviously if there is no `Date` you need to use a correct word (here Температура). See update

Comment: @IbratUsmonov a brief edit, though not necessary

out = (pd.read_csv("data_1.txt", header=None)[0]
         .str.split(r':\s*', n=1, expand=True)
         .assign(index=lambda d: d[0].eq('Date').cumsum())
         .pivot(index='index', columns=0, values=1)
       ).reset_index(drop=True)